# basex install on Centos7 failed with: Could not find lucene-contrib Java extension for this JVM

Tags: java, lucene, basex

I am installing basex on CentOS 7. I have a vanilla installation with EPEL.
I added the BaseX repo correctly and installed basex RPM using yum.

```
yum install basex.noarch
```

When i start basex server with `systemctl start basexserver` it starts fine but has problems with the supporting files.
I have been able to resolve most of the missing files by installing additional packages. e.g.

```
yum install tagsoup
yum install xml-commons-resolver
yum install clucene-core
yum install clucene-contrib
```

When i restart and look at the status of basexserver I see the following message.

```
systemd[1]: Starting BaseX database server...
basexserver[17537]: /usr/bin/build-classpath: Could not find lucene-contrib Java extension for this JVM
basexserver[17537]: /usr/bin/build-classpath: Could not find lucene-contrib Java extension for this JVM
basexserver[17537]: /usr/bin/build-classpath: error: Some specified jars were not found
basexserver[17537]: BaseX 8.3 [Server]
basexserver[17537]: Server was started (port: 1984).
```

I had expected installing clucene-contrib to solve the issue as installing clucene-core solved an earlier missing JVM.

Comment: This seems like an issue with the packaging, which is better brought to the BaseX mailing list or bug tracker. Also try to run the .zip distribution, if this works fine, some packaging problem can be assumed.

Comment: Hmmm. Just tried the zip download and this seems to run happily. So I have raised this on the git issue tracking: https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/issues/1287